# Dump of and documentation on the Magento 2.0 database

Tags: mysql, magento

The only references I can find to the Magento 2.0 database are just brief commentary.  Where could I get a full mysqldump file of the entire database?  AS long as it's innoDB I can review that and probably learn a lot.  Documentation would be helpful of course too.

I have seen this for 1.x - https://wiki.magento.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=9502821

but nothing similar for 2.0.  Thanks.

Comment: MageReverse.com used to be a good source for that, but it seems like everyone gave up at around 1.7.0.2 and as to Version 2.0, even yet, it's not nailed down enough for Module developers not to experience a lot of pain doing re-dos and then retesting.

Answer (score 0):

you can take complete mysql dump of your Magento 2.0 database by AdminDashboard->system->backups->databasebackup and after backup the file will be listed in grid and you can download it

Comment: This presumes I have installed Magento or want to